# The meaning of "fully paid"

Tags: terminology

What is the meaning of "fully paid" in the airline industry? Based on my [research](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fully%20paid) it's an adjective and it means "paid for at full face value with no further money due from the stockholder", but I found the following sentence in this [link](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g1-i10702-k11993696-WestJet_changed_my_fully_paid_for_flight_without_permission-Air_Travel.html) where a poster uses it as a noun. if I have asked the question on the wrong forum, I apologize and please let me know. Thank you.

"WestJet service centre and was told they changed our fully paid for flights to one a day later."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, I don't think it's a noun; I believe it's describing "flights." The poster here is saying that they had booked flights, the flights were fully paid for, and the airline changed the date for whatever reason.

The poster likely added "fully paid for" to emphasize that they had completed the transaction and purchased the flights before the date was changed. The exact point when that happens could be complicated to describe because of the vagaries of airline ticketing systems, but a consumer will typically view their flight as fully paid for once they've finished purchasing the tickets or at least once they've received an email confirmation of their booking.

Comment: In the rainy season in Bolivia your fully-paid-for flight might actually finally take place a week or more after the contracted date.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your explanation!